# Help with no theme beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to produce a beamer presentation with slides format like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textpos} % It is for place the logo on the header

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mwe}    

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt} TU Darmstadt $|$ fnb $|$ Dynamics and Vibration Group $|$ KWT Presentation \hfill \insertpagenumber}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
{%
\begin{textblock*}{10mm}(0.85\textwidth,-0.4cm)
\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-a.jpg}

\end{textblock*}}

{\flushleft\bf\Large\insertframetitle}}



\begin{document}



\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Brake Disk with Holes}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[p]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[p]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I get the lines under and above the header and above the footer?. I tried already with the `\addtobeamertemplate{headline}` and
`\addtobeamertemplate{footline}` comands, but they didn´t work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this question should go to the main site.

Comment: Please use the `mwe` package. AFAIK, it ships images. We will have trouble to compile your MWE otherwise, since we do not have your pictures.

Comment: `graphicx` and `amsmath` are already loaded by `beamer`. You shouldn't load them once more.

Comment: Even with `mwe`, I cannot compile your MWE. Something breaks in preamble. Please check what is the trouble (on first sight there is one unopened brace on the `insertframetitle`line, but deleting it doesn't help. I give up.

Comment: @Alfredo have you tried to use or tweak tudbeamer-class? http://exp1.fkp.physik.tu-darmstadt.de/tuddesign/

Comment: To amend the comment by @DG': the source code for such a presentation can be found at https://github.com/bebro/tuddesign

Comment: @DG' Could you convert your comment into an answer? Why reinvent the wheel when the finished class is available online?

Comment: @sztruks Please note that it is not necessary to load the `mwe` package to use `example-image-a` etc in a document. It just needs to be installed. Personally I don't think it is a good idea to add/remove package from a MWE in a question, this may hide the true problem of an OP

Comment: @samcarter done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a non-official implementation of TU Darmstadt's corporate design here:

- http://exp1.fkp.physik.tu-darmstadt.de/tuddesign/
- https://github.com/tudadesign/tudadesign

If you need help tweaking it, feel free to ask a new question.

A short example:

```
\documentclass[accentcolor=tud1b,aspectratio=169]{tudbeamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
test
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked very fine. Thanks a lot @user36296!